# How can I do concatenate strings in MySQL column comments?

Tags: mysql, sql, comments

I am trying to add a long in-database comment without line breaks, while having a reasonable line length in my SQL input file.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  bar   VARCHAR(63)    NOT NULL
  COMMENT 'This is the beginning of a very long comment that goes on and on and on. I want this line to be part of the same logical line while having newlines in the input source code.',
```

I would like to break the above line in my source code (SQL file), while keeping the same output in the database. The output in the database is defined to be the output of `SELECT column_comment from information_schema.columns where table_name='foo'`.

Using `+` for string concatenation, as one would do in many other programming languages, does not work. I have also tried using `CONCAT` but that also does not work. I am trying to achieve the equivalent of the following.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  bar   VARCHAR(63)    NOT NULL
  COMMENT 'This is the beginning of a very long comment' +
          ' that goes on and on and on. I want this line' +
          ' to be part of the same logical line while' +
          ' having newlines in the input source code.',
```

Is it possible to concatenate strings in these MySQL COMMENT strings?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want a multi-line comment in the sql definition, or single line in the definition and multi-line in "source code"? and what do you mean by "source code"? Is the master create in a string in a program? Otherwise, that CREATE statement is pretty much the closest thing there is to a schema's "source code".

Comment: @Uueerdo, I want a single line in the definition (that is, when I use `SELECT column_comment from information_schema.columns where table_name='foo'`)  and multi-line in the source code. The source code is a file called `foo.sql` in this case.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it. The comment is a literal string, not an expression. BTW, string concatenation in MySQL is done with the `CONCAT()` function, not the `+` operator.

Comment: In normal string expressions you can simply put quoted strings next to each other, like `set @foo = 'str1' 'str2';`. But I tried this with comments in `CREATE TABLE` and it didn't work.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried  with `CONCAT` as well but that didn't work either.

Comment: Of course it didn't. Like I said, it has to be a literal, not an expression.

Comment: I was just pointing that out for other places where you need to do concatenation, since you seemed to assume that `+` would work like in some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, in MySQL you don't have an operator like "+" to concatenate strings. concat() is the basic approach here.

I've had the same problem, and I use this sproc to solve this limitation through DDL. This code actually adds comment to the table-as-a-whole, while you asked about adding comments to individual fields. I hope this example is sufficiently helpful to adapt to your needs. And lastly, this code is at best 'prototype' quality. It works for me just fine (haven't actually used it much yet), but might not work for you:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`strompf`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_comment_to_table`(
    in_table_name   tinytext,
    in_comment      varchar(1024)
)
BEGIN
#
# Add comment to the given table
################################################################################
#
#
################################################################################
# Create DDL
################################################################################
#
set @ddl=concat
(
    'alter table ', in_table_name, ' comment=', 
    char(34), in_comment, char(34),';'
);

# select @ddl;

################################################################################
# Execute DDL
################################################################################
#
prepare ps1 from @ddl;
execute ps1;
drop prepare ps1;

END
```